# Haskell: What's the underlying data structure for list?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

If it's linked list, why doesn't it support push_back?

If it's simply array, why does it need linear time when accessed by subscript?

Appreciated for your help.

---

Edit: We can append element in front of a list like this `1:[2,3]`, that's push_front; but we can't do it this way: `[2,3]:4`, that's push_back.

ps. actually I borrow push_front/back from C++'s STL

Comment: I suspect it is a linked list, but I'm not sure what `push_back` is.  Could you explain?

Comment: Haskell list are singly linked list. As @BlackVegetable says, what do you mean by `push_back` ?

Comment: I believe C++ list<T> is doubly-linked whereas haskell's list is singly-linked so only adding to the front can be done efficiently.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Data.Dequeue](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dequeue-0.1.5/docs/Data-Dequeue.html) which has support for amortised O(1) pushBack and pushFront.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell list are singly linked list. It supports appending to the end of the list, but it has to traverse the entire list for this operation.:

```
λ> let x = [1,2,3]
λ> x ++ [4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: To be noted, the cost of push_back comes from the persistent aspect of the variable, you have to generate a brand new list as you can't modify your old list in place.

Answer (score 3):

If by `push_back` you mean adding an element to the end, of course it "supports" it. To add an element `x` to a list `list` (and get a new list so constructed), use the expression `list ++ [x]`.

Beware though, that this is an O(n) operation, n being the length of `list`.

That's because it is a singly linked list. It also answers your other question about subscript.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question asks about the "underlying implementation":

The list type is (conceptually) defined like this:

```
data [a] = [] | a:[a]
```

You can't actually write this declaration, because lists have funky syntax. But you can make exactly the same kind of thing yourself

```
data List a = Nil | a :* List a
infixr 5 :*
```

When you write something like `[1,2,3]`, that's just special syntax for `1:2:3:[]`. Since `:` associates to the right, this really means `1:(2:(3:[]))`. The functions on lists are all, fundamentally, based on pattern matching, which deals with just one constructor at a time. You may have to open up a lot of `:` constructors to get to the end of a list, and then build a bunch of `:` constructors to put together a new version with an extra element at the end. Any functions (like `++`) that you may use will end up going through this sort of process internally.